# Google interview, can somebody confirm this bit string algorithm, pure hypothesis

Tags: algorithm

This was a Google question i didn't figure out was right or wrong but a 2nd opinion never hurt. but the question is "given an n length bit-string solve for the number of times "111" appeared in all possible combinations."

now i know to find total combinations is 2^n what took me trouble was figuring out the number of occurrences i did find a pattern in occurrences but who knows for sure what happens when n becomes vast.

My logical solution was

```
#Level (n length)   # combos   # strings with "111" in it
_________________   ________   _____________________________
0                   0          0
1("1" or "0")       2          0
2("11","01" etc.    4          0
3                   8          1("111")
4                   16         3
5                   32         8
6                   64         20
------------------------------------Everything before this is confirmed
7                   128        49
8                   256        119
9                   512        288
10                  1000       696
```

etc.. i can post how i came up with the magical fairy dust but yeah

Comment: Can you explain more about your solution?

Comment: Just want to ask, what do you mean by "the number of times"? do you mean "the number of different strings"? For e.g. n=4, "1111", this string counts for 1 or 2?  (1 because it contains "111", 2 because "111" appears 2 times)

Comment: 1 because it contains "111" so something like 11111 is equal to 1 combination and 10111 also anywhere 111 exists. Pham when i did my solution i found a pattern that seemed to work

i converted the bit strings with 111 in them and turn them into decimals and saw a pattern

starting with level = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can help you with a solution:

Call the function to calculate number of string with n bit contains 111 is `f(n)`

- If the first bit of the string is 0, we have `f(n) += f(n - 1)//0 + (n - 1 bits)`
- If the first bit of the string is 1, we have `f(n) += f(n - 2) + f(n - 3) + 2^(n - 3)`

More explanation for case first bit is 1

If the first bit is 1, we have three cases:

- `10 + (n - 2 bits) =  f(n - 2)`
- `110 + (n - 3 bits) = f(n - 3)`
- `111 + (n - 3 bits) = 2^(n - 3)` as we can take all combinations.

So in total `f(n) = f(n - 1) + f(n - 2) + f(n - 3) + 2^(n - 3)`.

Apply to our example:

```
n = 4 -> f(4) = f(3) + f(2) + f(1) + 2^1 = 1 + 0 + 0 + 2 = 3;
n = 5 -> f(5) = f(4) + f(3) + f(2) + 2^2 = 3 + 1 + 0 + 4 = 8;
n = 6 -> f(6) = f(5) + f(4) + f(3) + 2^3 = 8 + 3 + 1 + 8 = 20;
n = 7 -> f(7) = f(6) + f(5) + f(4) + 2^4 = 20 + 8 + 3 + 16 = 47;
n = 8 -> f(8) = f(7) + f(6) + f(5) + 2^5 = 47 + 20 + 8 + 32 = 107;
n = 9 -> f(9) = f(8) + f(7) + f(6) + 2^6 = 107 + 47 + 20 + 64 = 238;
```